# convert pencil handwriting to pen handwriting online free

Tags: gratis, pdf, pdf-editor

I have pdfs of my homework assignment written in pencil. I was supposed to write it in pen. I am looking for a software that changes the colour of my handwriting to blue/black colour. Please help, Thanks in advance!

Edit: I wrote my homework assignment in a ruled notebook, then I scanned the images, and

something like this, for example,

[image: Mohandas K. Gandhi, letter in indelible pencil, South Africa 1909.jpg]

Basically, a pencil handwriting can be erased by eraser. It is light.

I found a very useful free PDF colour inverter online: [invert-pdf.club](https://invert-pdf.club/) (Perfect for printing dark PDFs.)

I found another website: [online2pdf.com/pdf-change-color-to-black-and-white](https://online2pdf.com/pdf-change-color-to-black-and-white) I can change the pdf color to grayscale or monochrome.

BUt i am still not able to find a tool that changes color blue/black

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [GNU GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/). You can 1) change to grey scale (Image > Mode, it is second menu item) 2) change contrast and brightness first so that the background is more white (under Color menu) 3) change back to color mode (Image > MODE) 4) adjust blue color balance there (under Color menu)

Though I would suggest first to put the document under a glass and improve the lighting in the room. If you don't have glass you can use something simple transparent like a refridgerator shelf. Even if it is missing, moving the document to a better lit area would help.

Tried it and got this:

[image]

If I skip the contrast editing and just do step 4, then here is what it looks like:

[image]